# compound attribute in ezpublish content class

Tags: ezpublish

I am designing a content class in ezpublish 5 where i need a filed like `rating in different categories`. I want to give content editor an interface in admin panel where he can choose a category to rate from  dropdown and then text field to put rating point (1-5).

How to achieve this in ezpublish5?

Answer (score 1):

The Matrix data/fieldtype sounds like it's close to what you need.

It allows you to set a table of values with a set number of columns. The limitation here is that each field is a free text entry for users.

```
| Review            |   Rating    |  Notes             |
|-------------------|-------------|--------------------|
| Customer Service  |     5       |  Friendly & polite |
| Quality of Food   |     4       |  Tasty & Plentiful |
| ...               |    ...      |  ...               |
```

There is a symfony bundle available for the Matrix fieldtype to allow access to the data in the Symfony stack: https://github.com/ezcommunity/EzMatrixFieldTypeBundle.

Alternatively there is the option to create your own data/fieldtype: http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/creating-datatypes-in-ez-publish-4 & https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/eZ+Publish+5+Field+Type+Tutorial